# how to get a numerical result for exp sympy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, sympy

I need derivative a exp numerical function but when i use "diff" function from "sympy" with exponential (exp(-x) for example) thats works but when i put a number into a exp() the output shows me exp(number) not the real result, only shows me the symbolic result, i want a number result.

Code:

```
import math
from sympy import *

x=symbols('x')
F=exp(-x)
dx=diff(F,x)

print(dx)
print(dx.subs({x:4}))
```

Output:

```
-exp(-x)
-exp(-4)
```

i want a number like
`-0.01831563888873418`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use evalf:

```
import math
from sympy import *

x=symbols('x')
F=exp(-x)
dx=diff(F,x)

print(dx)
print(dx.evalf(subs={x: 4}))
```